# Angular app displaying "&#40" instead of "("

Tags: angular

I'm doing an HTTP request which returns some JSON.  I then link it to my html using   {{}}.  characters such as "(" are showing up as "&#40".  How do I convert this to normal characters.  Using Angular CLI 7.0.3.

One item of the JSON returned from my request is:

```
"style": {
        "description": "Imperial stouts are usually extremely dark brown to 
         black in color with flavors that are intensely malty, deeply 
         roasted and sometimes with accents of dark fruit &#40raisin,
         fig&#41 and chocolate. The bitterness is typically low to moderate. 
         Imperial stouts are strong and generally exceed 8% ABV."
      }
```

the HTML is:

```
<div class='col-lg-4'>
<p>{{beer.description}}</p>
<p>{{beer.style.description}}</p>
</div>
```

I want &#40raisin, fig&#41 to read (raisin,fig)

Comment: please share some relevant code

Comment: Also mention the angular version you are using

Comment: mystring.replace(/&#40/g, "("); You need to manually apply str_replace().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [innerHtml] property for this :

```
<p [innerHtml]="beer.description"></p>
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  What exactly is it with putting it there that made the difference?  Is it better to always link to my data this way, or is it more beneficial to use the {{...}} in some situations?

Comment: Angular uses {{property}} for interpolation of values. That is the way that you would display plain text and for html codes like &#41 you would use innerHtml